# Bash-on-windows kubuntu missing titlebar with close/move/resize bars

Tags: xorg

Using kstart plasmashell I get the desktop but without bar with close button or to resize move the window, hopefully this isn't display server issue. I'm using VcXsrv.

Comment: Can you try a different x server ? Xming - https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/

Comment: It's incredibly slow (outdated), and I belief plasma5 tries to mess around with wayland, perhaps there's a way to force it to run on Xserver exclusively. Running xfce4 will work. I also tried to install with backports since 16.04 requires them I belief (which I'm not sure I did on the whole), I would imagine using backports would force Xserver...